# Yii - find records with zero related records

Tags: activerecord, yii, yii1.x

There are two models: `Auteurs` and `Books`. `Auteurs` model contains following relations:

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'books' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Books','a_liens(id_auteur,id_book)'),
        'booksCount' => array(self::STAT, 'Books', 'a_liens(id_auteur,id_book)'),
    );
}
```

How to write criteria to get all `Auteurs` with zero `booksCount`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of counting books, you may just find `Auteurs` models without any book - result is the same, but question is different. You may achieve this by using `LEFT JOIN` and finding records with missing books:

```
$auteurs->with([
    'books' => [
        'together' => true,
        'select' => false,
        'joinType' => 'LEFT JOIN',
        'condition' => 'books.id IS NULL',
    ],
]);
```